# How to fetch the nth highest record from a table without using system function like TOP, MAX and Order by ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Interviewer asked me the above question.

I knew the 3 way. Is there any other way to find nth highest record?

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: May I ask why this question is considered as too broad? It is nice SQL question.

Comment: OK, it is really sad that it was marked as too broad. I could agree that OP didn't show own effort, but in my opinion question is perfectly valid. It is classic problem(nth value) but with constraints (could not use clauses `TOP/ORDER BY` and `MAX/MIN` aggregate functions) which make it even more interesting.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . I didn't vote to close, but it is poorly specified because it doesn't explain what to do with ties and `NULL` values.  But I can think of multiple ways:  `row_number()`, `dense_rank()`, `count(*) over`, subqueries with ALL, subqueries with correlation clauses, self-`join` with aggregation, inserting into a table with an auto-increment column . . . and I haven't had coffee yet.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree that they are multiple ways and this question is about it. OP clearly said that he wants to avoid `ORDER BY`  and aggregations so we could exclude: windowed functions/self-join with aggregation and insert into autoincrement table. That's the  beauty of this question - it is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive approach using `> ALL` and stacked cte:

```
-- highest
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE col > ALL (SELECT col
                 FROM tab t2
                 WHERE t1.col < t2.col);

-- 2nd highest
WITH c1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tab t1
  WHERE col > ALL (SELECT col
                 FROM tab t2
                 WHERE t1.col < t2.col)
)
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE col < ALL (SELECT col FROM c1)
  AND col > ALL (SELECT col
                 FROM tab t2
                 WHERE t1.col < t2.col 
                   AND col < ALL(SELECT col FROM c1))
```

And then you could stack this kind of query multiple times.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3642cba38459bbadf49247ae70afd69)**

In case of ties it will work same as `DENSE_RANK`:

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c00f5b8fa8c4b736c730846a26dadd51)**

Comment: The interviewer wanted to test your knowledge of ranking functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @RemusRusanu `ROW_NUMBER()` has `ORDER BY` clause inside `OVER`. How about knowledge of recursive CTE?